# uploading images - do they have domain name in them - chrome not sending session id

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, cookies

For testing I downloaded images from the net and uploaded using valum file upload in chrome...chrome is not sending session cookie along with these request header( I dont see that in the server side/though I see it on developer tool)...does chrome know that these images are from different domain . what is happening...Is there work around for this to pass the session id (as cookie). It is also happening in IE10 which makes me belive it is some standard. and not just a chrome issue. This problem is not there with firefox/safari/opera

It is fine when uploading to localhost. only when uploading to different server with domain name there is this problem leading to creating a new session for this.

Update:
I have added xhr.withCredentials = true still no use.
Also added on the server side to the upload url...

```
res.setHeader 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
res.setHeader 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true
```

I dont know how helpful this would be, because I would have already sent the upload file and response header will not of much help.

basically the problem is I don't have access to the session variable at the server side, since the session id/sid cookie is not coming back /I am not able to save some of this upload details into the current session(because this is a new session) .

Update:
I tried creating an image in teh desktop using paint..even then chrome would not sent the cookies. Really drives me crazy...

Comment: Are the cookies being send with all other requests?

Comment: yes. with image upload(which are my own) wierd how google knows it...the same with ie10. for images I download from net when I tried to upload to my server...cookies wouldn't go

Comment: Have you checked if the domain and path of your session cookie match the URL used for the upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the uploader is using Flash under some circumstances to do the upload. There is a bug in Flash which prevents cookies being sent for these types of requests. This would explain the behaviour you are seeing. The workaround is to pass in the sessionId and transmit it in a different way eg. querystring.

Comment: possibly..may be a little more explanation how/what is making possible would be nice..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to get the basics out of the way, this is unrelated to the origin of the image.  Chrome or other browsers don't care where you get your images.

It's rather difficult to guess exactly what's going on, would have helped to see a jsfiddle or some more setup explanation, but based on what I'm guessing, you might be using different domains for the page where the upload button is hosted and the target url where you're sending your files (even using ssl for one and http for the other makes it different).  Even different subdomains will not allow cookies to be passed if the cookies were not set with a base domain (yourdomain.com)

So, if sub-domains are the problem, you know what to do - set a base domain so you get your cookies to go on any sub domain.
If it's http vs. https you need to always use https (or http) because you can't switch cookies between those two.

If that's not it, or if you're using completely different domains, you can access your cookies locally via script (if they're not marked as http only) and add them to the upload request.  Valum 2.0 (don't know about v1.0) lets you add parameters to the request like so:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
        action: '/server-side.upload',
        // additional data to send, name-value pairs
        params: {
            param1: 'value1',
            param2: 'value2'
        }
    });
```

You can't set cookies on a domain which is not the page's domain via script so for using completely different domains your only choice is using request params.

Comment: If domain name difference is the case it should have been for every image that I uploaded. But for some images it is sending the cookies/session gets picked up and for the ones from internet it is not sending the cookie/new session gets created. I wish I could share the url but this is a public forum..and I don't want to get my server bogged down...

Comment: I don't if the js fiddle would help..it is simple file upload to the same domain..http://jsfiddle.net/b9cc84aa/

Comment: since it is a session cookie..it is marked as http only..so I am using params thing to pass the session back and doing the comparision.

Comment: If and only if you were able to get this to work with JPG images, let's try a different path to see if size has anything to do with it: take one of the images that did not work, make sure it is a JPG, open it via an image editing tool, and save it back as a jpg but with more compression (you can resize it to a smaller size to get the same effect).  Now check if the difference in size makes a difference (it is accepted).